# how to select row words as columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select words from the rows as columns and remove same words from row afterwards.

I tried to see pandas functions like .pivot and things alike but didn't word.

Here is my input

```py
['Sampling frequency: 8000 Hz',
 'Number of channels: 2 (16-bit integer)',
 'File name: /home/niraj/Documents/audiofiles/M1F1-int16.wav',
 'Sampling frequency: 8000',
 'Sampling frequency: 16000 Hz',
 'Number of channels: 1 (16-bit integer)',
 'File name: /home/niraj/Documents/jg00b1ss.wav',
 'Sampling frequency: 16000',
 'sample_rate: 16000',
 'Sampling frequency: 8000 Hz',
 'Number of channels: 2 (16-bit integer)',
 'File name: /home/niraj/Documents/M1F1-int16.wav',
 'Sampling frequency: 8000']
```

The expected output I am looking for is this

```
    File name                sample_rate   Sampling frequency    Number of channels                                        
0  /home/niraj/Documents...  16000           8000Hz               2(16-bit integer)
```

where the information is not found it can be either blank or N/A

Comment: Why is there only one output for your input? Also, you should add code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, every records begins with a "Sampling frequency" data, and begins with some other values that may or may not exist.

we can iterate your data and divide it to records based on this key, then make a DataFrame from those records:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = ['Sampling frequency: 8000 Hz',
 'Number of channels: 2 (16-bit integer)',
 'File name: /home/niraj/Documents/audiofiles/M1F1-int16.wav',
 'Sampling frequency: 8000',
 'Sampling frequency: 16000 Hz',
 'Number of channels: 1 (16-bit integer)',
 'File name: /home/niraj/Documents/jg00b1ss.wav',
 'Sampling frequency: 16000',
 'sample_rate: 16000',
 'Sampling frequency: 8000 Hz',
 'Number of channels: 2 (16-bit integer)',
 'File name: /home/niraj/Documents/M1F1-int16.wav',
 'Sampling frequency: 8000']

records = []
for line in data:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if key == "Sampling frequency":
        records.append({key:value})
    records[-1][key]=value

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)

print(df)
```

pandas will already use `NaN` for every field that is missing from a record.